# How to change focus from one editbox to another in android

Tags: android

I have three editboxes which has retrict to enter only one numeric digit on each box.when i enter the value of first box the focus should be moved from 1st box to 2nd.After entering value to 2nd box.,its focus should automatically moved to 2nd to 3rd like that i need to do.Could anybody help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use requestFocus() API to shift the focus from the code,
Keep listening for the text, using textWatcher, once specified limit is reached, call     EditTextreference.requestFocus() to shift the focus.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.Do u have any sample code.so that i can understand much better

Comment: Ahh.. I dont have, I would say , search for textwatcher class usage and then its just one line of calling requestfocus.

Answer (score 1):

This code moves focus from one EditText to another when EditText length greater than 1.

```
   EditText et1,et2;

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id1);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id2);

   et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int count, int after)
        {
        // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int before, int count)
        {
            Integer textlength = et1.getText().length();
            if(textlength>=1){      //If text length greater than 1 move to next EditText

                et2.requestFocus();

            }

        }
    });
```